Is there a more non-uniform set with positive measure in any rectangle of the 2-d plane, where the measures don't equal the area of the rectangles?
(If you don't need the motivation, skip it.)
Motivation: I want to find a set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ which is more non-uniform and difficult to meaningfully average than this set. I need such a set to test my theory.

Suppose $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is Borel and $B$ is a rectangle of $\mathbb{R}^2$. In addition, suppose the Lebesgue measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is $\lambda(\cdot)\;\!$:

Question: Is there an explicit $A$, such that:

$\lambda(A\cap B)>0$ for all $B$

$\lambda(A\cap B)\neq\lambda(B)$ for all $B$

For all rectangles $\mathscr{B}\subseteq B$
a. $\lambda(B\setminus\mathscr{B})>\lambda(\mathscr{B})\Rightarrow\lambda(A\cap(B\setminus\mathscr{B}))<\lambda(A\cap\mathscr{B})$
b. $\lambda(B\setminus\mathscr{B})<\lambda(\mathscr{B})\Rightarrow\lambda(A\cap(B\setminus\mathscr{B}))>\lambda(A\cap\mathscr{B})$
c. $\lambda(B\setminus\mathscr{B})=\lambda(\mathscr{B})\Rightarrow\lambda(A\cap(B\setminus\mathscr{B}))\neq\lambda(A\cap\mathscr{B})$?



If so, how do we define such a set? If not, how do we modify the question so explicit $A$ exists?
Edit: According to a user on reddit,

Let's just use $\mathbb{R}$ so "rectangles" are just intervals.
Your conditions in 3 imply $\lambda(A\cap(2,3)) >
 \lambda(A\cap(0,2))$, and condition 1 implies $\lambda(A \cap (0,2))
 >\lambda(A\cap(1,2))$. So $\lambda(A \cap (2,3)) > \lambda(A\cap(1,2))$. Likewise, $\lambda(A\cap(1,2)) > \lambda(A
 \cap(2,4))$ and $\lambda(A\cap(2,4)) > \lambda(A\cap(2,3))$, so
$\lambda(A\cap(1,2)) > \lambda(A\cap(2,3))$, which is a contradiction.

Does this apply to $\mathbb{R}^2$? Are the conditions in this question nonsensical?
